# Understanding Crashlytics Error Logs

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics to track and fix crashes in my live app. However, I am not very knowledgeable on how to understand what the thread is telling me.

Usually on XCode, you get specific information regarding the error (such as, "unexpectedly found nil", etc.). Is there such information in a Crashlytics Dashboard? If not, how can I understand better what is causing the crash in the app?

Here is a picture of an example crash.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You error is inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. If I'm not mistaken, The blue labels are methods inside your classes.

And they work like a bread crumbs trail for all the processes that happened until the crash. 0 is the first interaction where N is the last method triggered before your app crashed.

But you must agreed with me that your problem probably isn't inside UIKit or Foundation methods, right?
Is that helpful?

If not, feel free to contact their support, they are really responsive!
Here is they're email: support@fabric.io